# toString method does not display but code compiles

Tags: java, oop, tostring

Java code compiles but the toString method does not display. Do I need to call it in the subclass? or is there a different way for the toString to display the instance variables?

```
public class Animal { 
    //instance variables
    private int numberOfLegs; 
    private boolean sleep; 

    //Default Constructor
    public Animal() {
        numberOfLegs = 6;
        sleep = true;
    }

    // Constructor
    public Animal(int numberOfLegs, boolean sleep){
        this.numberOfLegs = numberOfLegs;
        this.sleep = sleep;
    }

    //toString method
    public String toString (int numberOfLegs, boolean sleep){
        return numberOfLegs + " legs, sleep: " + sleep;
    }
    //walk method
    void walk(){
        System.out.print("walking ");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal1 = new Tiger();
        animal1.walk();
        animal1.toString(4, false);
    } //end main
}// end animalclass

class Tiger extends Animal {
    void walk(){
        super.walk();
        System.out.println("a Tiger");
    }
    public Tiger(){
        super();
    }
} //end Tiger class
```

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` **returns** a `String`. It does not perform any display logic (unlike your `walk()` method which prints things and returns nothing).

You need to display it with `System.out.println()` or other means.

The `toString()` method also shouldn't be taking arguments. You already know how many legs the animal has, so the parameters are useless.